# How to find out if an event occurred between two other events

Tags: r, function, events, boundary

I need to find out how many times an instance of one variable occurred between two instances of another variable. Given the data:

```
v <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
w <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
z <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I want to see this:

```
some_function(v, w)
> 2

some_function(w, x)
> 1

some_function(w, y)
> 0

some_function(v, z)
> 1
```

Such that the first argument of `some_function()` demarcates windows within which I can check whether anything happened in the second argument. Note that the output should not distinguish between the event happening once or twice within each window, but rather should count the number of windows within which one or more events occurred.

Comment: Can you clarify why `some_function(w, z)` would return 0?

Comment: what should you return in the case of `x=c(1,0,0,1),y=c(1,0,0,1)` or in the case of `x=c(1,0,1,0,1);y=c(1,0,1,0,1)`?

Comment: Dan Hall, it shouldn't -- that was an error. Sorry about that.

Comment: Onyambu, good point. In the case of the first one, it should return 1, since falling right on the boundary should either count as the falling in the previous window or the following window. Likewise, the second case you gave should return 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowsum()`, grouped by `cumsum()`.  This should be pretty quick.

```
some_function <- function(a, b) sum(rowsum(b, cumsum(a)) > 0)

some_function(v, w)
# [1] 2
some_function(w, x)
# [1] 1
some_function(w, y)
# [1] 0
some_function(w, z)  ## possible typo in question
# [1] 1
some_function(v, z)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: I wonder if the function should return zero for something like `x <- c(1, 0, 1)` and `y <- c(1, 0, 0)`?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
some_function <- function(a, b){
  sum(sapply(split(b, cumsum(a)), sum) > 0)
}

> some_function(v, w)
[1] 2
> some_function(w, x)
[1] 1
> some_function(w, y)
[1] 0
> some_function(w, z) # Not sure why you are getting 0 here?
[1] 1
> some_function(v, z)
[1] 1
```

Comment: `some_function(c(1,0,1),c(1,0,1))` gives 2??? should it not return 0? just curious..check @Henrik comment

Answer (score 1):

Another approach based on `findInterval()`:

```
some_function <- function(x, y) {
  sum(unique(findInterval(which(y==1), which(x==1), left.open=TRUE)) != 0)
}

> some_function(v, w)
[1] 2
> some_function(w, x)
[1] 1
> some_function(w, y)
[1] 0
> some_function(w, z) # Probably a mistake in the question
[1] 1
> some_function(v, z)
[1] 1
```

Comment: `length(unique(findInterval(which(!!val), which(!!win))))` gives the same result. But it seems incorrect though...

Comment: @Henrik You mean there are some cases where this would give an incorrect results?

Comment: I mean that _my_ function gives incorrect results...e.g. for `x <- c(1, 0, 1)` and `y <- c(1, 0, 0)`.